# orderBy child Time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Here is my database and i want to arrange them by time...

My Code

```
mTimeReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages").child(UID).child(userId);
mTimeReference.orderByChild("Time").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String time = dataSnapshot.child("Time").getValue().toString();
            String message = dataSnapshot.child("Message").getValue().toString();
            LastSeen lastSeeen = new LastSeen();
            long lastTime = Long.parseLong(time);
            String lastSeenTime = lastSeeen.lastSeen(lastTime, getActivity());
            if(lastSeenTime == null) {
                holder.setTime("Just Now");
            }
            else {
                holder.setTime(lastSeenTime);
            }
            holder.setMessage(message);
            linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I have an activity where all my friends ids are shown. I want them to be shown in the order of the time in the database (the last they texted).

My present code isn't working.

*If you can't figure out the problem at least tell me the how to put an item of a RecyclerView on top. Like if i want to put the friend B on top how do I do it?*

Comment: If you are trying to log for example the `message` String, in the logcat, do you have the desired order? Please responde with @.

Comment: What isn't working about the desired code? I.e. if you run this code for the two friends you've highlighted in the screenshot, and you print the keys of the snapshots: what does it print? And what did you expect?

Comment: It prints the friends but not in the order of the time @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: No im not getting the desider output @AlexMamo

Comment: Maybe its because nowhere i have mentioned that i want to take only the last message by the friends and take the time of that

Comment: Look to the edited question please

Comment: Aha.... if you want to make each chat room display the timestamp of the last message in that room, you should store that value explicitly. So add a property `lastMessageTimestamp` to each room, and update that on each write.

Comment: No im able to fetch the last messages time... but not able to put everything in order... can u please help me out @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

You can either order the chats clientside or use an indexed firebase adapter.

For that you need to create an additional structure in your database, as so:

```
root
- Chats...
- Messages...
- UserActiveChats
  - UserId <- your id
    - FriendUserId: TimeStamp
    - FriendUserId: TimeStamp
```

Then you have to change your 'Add-Chat-Message (however you implemented it)' function to a WriteBatch which:

- Creates the ChatMessage (as now, at /Messages/userId/friendId/..)
- Creates/Sets the value at
  /UserActiveMessages/userId/friendId:ServerValue.TimeStamp

This way, you can create a query at /UserActiveMessages/myUserId and order it by value (timestamp), which represents the last time they sent a message to you. That way you will have an ordered list of the latest users who sent you a message. Then all you need to do is use a indexed FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to display the actual chats instead of just their userId.

```
keyQuery = rootReference.child('/UserActiveMessages/userId').orderByValue();
chatsRef = rootReference.child('/Messages/userId/');

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Chat> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chat>()
        .setIndexedQuery(keyQuery, chatsRef, Chat.class)
        .build();
```

see how to implement the rest here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data